# Create Polygon out of minX, minY, maxX, maxY

Tags: coordinates, geopandas, shapely, extents

I have a pandas dataframe with the min and max values from two polygons. How can I create two geometries (Polygons) out of these values using Geopandas or Shapely?

[image: dataframe]

Comment: Can you provide a tiny piece of code that creates such a GeoDataFrame so that the format is 100% clear? And what exactly do you mean by "two geometries"? Two rows in a GDF? Two independent Shapely geometry objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [shapely.geometry.box](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.geometry.box):

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import box

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"minx":[-168,42], "miny":[72,8], "maxx":[-162,-36], "maxy":[84,16]})
df["geometry"] = df.apply(lambda row: box(minx=row["minx"], miny=row["miny"], 
                                          maxx=row["maxx"], maxy=row["maxy"]), axis=1)
#df = df.set_crs(???)
df.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: perfect, this is what I was looking for!